# Showing message 'No data' when WPF DataGrid has no rows

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-3.5, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF `DataGrid` in which I want to show a message 'No data' when there are no records within it. So I have done what is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687414/show-no-record-found-message-on-a-wpf-datagrid-when-its-empty) in the answer provided by pchajer but when datagrid is show with no data the message is not show. I think I am having problems with `AncestorType`, I think I am not specifying correctly, but I do not know how to solve this. I do not understand at all how `AncestorType` works...

Below my code:

```
<Window x:Class="My.Apps.WPF.Test.wMain"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:My.Apps.WPF.Test">

<dg:DataGrid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="dg:DataGrid">
        <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.IsRecordExists, 
                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                  AncestorType={x:Type local:wMain}}}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="RowHeight" Value="0"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode" Value="Visible"></Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</dg:DataGrid.Style>

<!-- Missatge quan no hi ha documents pel procés seleccionat -->
<dg:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="No hi ha documents disponibles pel procés seleccionat" Width="400"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</dg:DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>

</Window>
```

Code-behind (XAML.cs):

```
namespace My.Apps.WPF.Test
{
    public partial class wMain : ViewBaseControl
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is this IsRecordExists property in wMain class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could bind to the `DataGrid`'s `HasItems` property and change the template:

```
<DataGrid.Style>
    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGrid">
                            <TextBlock Text="No data..." />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Style>
```

There will never be any row details to display if there are no rows in the `DataGrid` so that approach won't work.

**Edit:** If you want to display the column headers even when there are no rows, you should include a `DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter` in the template:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGrid">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="No data..." Grid.Row="1" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Ok, your solution works but datagrid column headers are not shown. Would be it possible with your example?

Comment: Then you need to include a DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter in the template. See my edit.

Comment: It says below error: Error 109 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' is not a valid value for property 'System.Windows.Controls.Control.Template' in Setter.

Comment: The Template property should be set to a ControlTemplate and nothing else as per my answer.

Comment: I don't know why you are using a dg prefix for the DataGrid in your sample code, but then it's the same for the TargetType, i.e.: `TargetType="dg:DataGrid"`

Comment: Because I am using WPF Toolkit in NET 3.5. Your two examples work perfectly. A lot of thanks man! I forgot to put line: <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGrid"> after <Setter.Value>

Comment: Modified this a bit to get the original styling: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76899353